# How to run a private Wolfram Mathematica Kernel on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, google-cloud-platform

I would like to be able to process the Wolfram Language through the command line of a computer with a large amount of memory. This seems to be easy to accomplish with GCP. I would create a large instance, use it for as long as necessary, and then delete the instance. I am curious, how would I install and set up Mathematica on GCP? I know that I can use a plain text input, but I do not know how to install and activate Mathematica just through the command line.

Comment: I don't know GCP.  How does it work?  Is it Linux based?  The Mathematica installer for Linux is command line only.  It comes as a shell script.  Just run it.  After you are done installing, run it.  It will walk you through the activation.  No graphical interface is needed.  Of course you are going to need the appropriate license—contact Wolfram Support for that: http://support.wolfram.com/contact

Answer (score 1):

yes, GCP has a special service named **Compute Engine**. You must create a Linux virtual machine from the interface. Use whatever linux distribution you are comfortable most. After that SSH into the machine and start following the steps outlined herein http://support.wolfram.com/kb/17399
Good luck